# How to root your own AOSP build?

Tags: root, android-source, android-10.0

We have root access to our AOSP build, when we use:

```
lunch smarc_mx8mq-eng
```

How can we get a root shell after using:

```
lunch smarc_mx8mq-user
```

This can be any form of temporary hack to the AOSP source, but the build must remain a user build.

I've read about `/` being mounted with `nosetuid`, but that doesn't seem to be the case for us:

```
smarc_mx8mq:/ # mount 
/dev/block/mmcblk1p5 on / type ext4 (ro,seclabel,relatime,block_validity,delalloc,barrier,user_xattr,acl,inode_readahead_blks=8)
```

(I will check this again once I have built a `user` build.)

What's the best way of rooting our own AOSP build?

Comment: To clarify, by root shell you mean via adb, right? Can you specify which Android version you are targeting? I did something like this some time ago, but it involved hitting some switch in the SE Linux rules, I would have to look up how I did it. (Also I guess `userdebug` instead of `eng` is not what you need?)

Comment: Also, one additional question, is it important to you to get root access during early boot, or is an authenticated ADB shell fine where you have to make some botton press on the UI of the device?

Comment: No, sorry, I can't use userdebug.  It's Android 10 (just added tag).  Root access is not needed until after booting has completed.  A button-press to trigger it would be fine.

Comment: It's also fine for root access to be gained with an arbitrary command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to flash the boot-debug.img into the boot partition.

```
$ sudo fastboot flash boot boot-debug.img
target reported max download size of 419430400 bytes
sending 'boot_a' (43252 KB)...
OKAY [  2.270s]
writing 'boot_a'...
OKAY [  2.163s]
finished. total time: 4.433s
...
$ adb shell
smarc_mx8mq:/ $ exit
$ adb root
restarting adbd as root
$ adb shell
smarc_mx8mq:/ #
```